# React children prop element used conditionally vs non-conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below scenario, `Child` is passed as `children` to `App` and declared directly inside `App` as it's child. Now the behaviour is that `Child` passed as `children` will not `render` when `App` get's rendered. Makes sense since it's passed from the top so if at the top a state changed happen then it would have `re-rendered` too.

```js
const {useState,useEffect} = React;

function App({children}) {
  const [state,setState] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={()=>setState(state=>state+1)}>Click Me</button>
       {<Child name="as children from app"/>}
       {children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({name}){
  console.log(`render ${name}`);
  return <div>123</div>
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <App >
      <Child name="as children from root"/>
    </App>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here's the conditional scenario :-

Whenever `state` is even, both `Child` components irrespective of whether passed as `children` or directly `declared` within `App` will be **unmounted** and **mounted** on each render of `App`.

```js
const {useState,useEffect} = React;

function App({children}) {
  const [state,setState] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={()=>setState(state=>state+1)}>Click Me</button>
       {state%2===0 && <Child name="as children from app"/>}
       {state%2===0 && children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({name}){
  useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(`${name} is mounted`)
  },[])
  console.log(`render ${name}`);
  return <div>123</div>
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <App >
      <Child name="as children from root"/>
    </App>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Why didn't React go for only **rendering** the `children` here instead of **unmounting** and **mounting** ?
The fact that it's passed from the top level doesn't matter for `children` here.

So am I right to assume from this that it doesn't matter how the **React component** is passed whether as `children` or declared directly, conditional showing the same will cause the component **unmount** and **mount** ?

Comment: It makes sense that it mounts and unmounts the child passed from `App` since it is not present in the virtual DOM when `state % 2 !== 0`. The other one however, I think it should keep it mounted ...

Comment: Yeah the other one passed as `{children}` that's what my question is around. If there is a chance to prevent it's **render** when `App` get's rendered, why does it directly stop being `mounted` when used conditionally ?

Answer (score 1):

`{true && children}` will *mount* (add in DOM) the `children`, and `{false && children}` will *unmount* (remove from DOM) the `children`.

Note that, in the case of `{false && children}`,  the `children` element has been *unmounted* but still **exists** in `props` of `App` component. In other words, props still has some data / object, but it is not being used to *mount* the related component or element.

---

Needless to say that `{true && <MyComponent/>}` will mount MyComponent and `{false && <MyComponent/>}` will unmount it. And, `MyComponent` doesn't exist in any `prop` unlike `children`.

---

As mentioned in [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx):

> In JSX expressions that contain both an opening tag and a closing tag, the content between those tags is passed as a special prop: `props.children`.

So, writing:

```
<Parent>
  <Child name="Via children prop" />
</Parent>
```

doesn't mount the `props.children` element. It only passes a special prop named *children* which gets mounted only when we write `{props.children}` inside `Parent`.

---

#### When will the component rendered via `props.children` re-render?

The `Child` component rendered via:

```
// In App.jsx component:

return (
  <div>
    {/* some code ... */}
    <Parent>
      <Child name="Via children prop" />
    </Parent>
  </div>
)
```

will re-render only when `App` (where `<Child />` is declared) re-renders or when, obviously, the `Child` itself does.

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/app-parent-child-children-props-e8og9).

Comment: I guess it makes sense, the interesting part in this case is why, in the first experiment, the "child from root" does not rerender when `App` rerenders, but I guess that's the difference ..."child from root" is a ready-made component passed to `App`. It doesn't rerender just because `App` rerenders but usage in `App` is required to mount it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) if you want to avoid re-rendering the component according to conditions.

You can also use [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for `<Child>`

Comment: `children` prop used conditionally is getting **unmounted** and **mounted** so `React.memo` is out of the picture. I am asking why `children` prop is getting **unmounted** and **mounted** in the first place ? If we can prevent it's `render` in first case, why does it stop being mounted when used **conditionally** ? It seems like a direct jump from being good for render optimisation to useless when used conditionally :p.

Comment: If the first case you're not removing anything from the tree based on state. In the second case you are. Read https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: How do you expect react to remove something from the DOM based on your given logic, and then not have to recreate it again when it should be displayed again?

In the first case you don't have any logic for rendering the children, they are always present so React can optimise the rendering

Comment: Basically whenever something `unmounts` which it will when shown conditionally, it doesn't matter whether it was available as `children` prop (across all renders) or directly declared , the `unmount` signify that the instance was destroyed and next time a new will be created ?